# alert dialog for internet connection

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created my app with some internet activities which load images in the list from service. I want to show an alert dialog with ok button when the internet or wifi connection is not available for the device.

Following is my code, but when I run my app with WiFi disabled it shows the message `"unfortunately app has stopped"`.

Thanks in advance

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Boolean  bs_netcheck;
    bs_netcheck = netCheck();
    if(bs_netcheck == true)
    {
        displayAlert();
    }


    ImageView logoimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoImage);

      Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://lh5.ggpht.com/_hepKlJWopDg/TB-_WXikaYI/AAAAAAAAElI/715k4NvBM4w/s144-c/IMG_0075.JPG").into(logoimage);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ImageView layout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawerlogo);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://devobal.in/live");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    ViewPager pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("TEACHING");
    spec.setIndicator("TEACHING", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_teachimg));
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2

    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("RESOURCES", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_teachimg));
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 3

    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("MRT", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_teachimg));
    host.addTab(spec);
    tab1Data();
    tab2Data();
    tab3Data();

    host.setCurrentTab(0);
   host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    for(int i=0;i<host.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        Intent gallery = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Gallery_Test.class);
        startActivity(gallery);


    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;


}



private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData(String val ) {

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetTeachingItems";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "GetTeachingItems";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://alive.devobal.com/PodioWebService.asmx?op=GetTeachingItems";

    ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    List<String> headlines = new LinkedList<>();

    Email = "dtiadmin1";
    Password = "DevObal1916";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        aht.debug = true;
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        Log.v("PCount", "" + resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount());
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        SoapObject obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;

        obj1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("diffgram");
        obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");

        //SrtVv="";
        for (int j = 0; j < obj2.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            obj4 = (SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(j);

            ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
            newsData.setUrl(obj4.getProperty(3).toString());
            newsData.setHeadline(obj4.getProperty(1).toString());
            newsData.setReporterName(obj4.getProperty(2).toString());
            newsData.setDate(obj4.getProperty(0).toString());

            listMockData.add(newsData);

        }

        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
        Response = res.toString();

        String strV = response.getProperty(0).toString();

        Log.v("TAG", response.toString());
        Log.v("TAG", res.toString());
        return listMockData;
        //return nameValues;
        // Log.v("TAG", com.WsApp.adapters.Constants.name);
    } catch (MalformedJsonException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public void tab1Data(){

    listData = getListData("");

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,listData);
    listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

    customListAdapter.setListData(getListData(""));
    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem newsData = (ListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final TextView itemidtemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempid);
            itemidtemp.setText(newsData.getDate());
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + newsData.getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent series = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeriesActivity.class);
            series.putExtra("itemid", itemidtemp.getText());
            series.putExtra("title",listData.get(position).getHeadline());
            startActivity(series);
            //          secondclick();

        }
    });
}



public void tab2Data() {
    listData2 = getListData2("");

    Log.v("bbbbbbbbb","bbbbbb"+listData2.size());

    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list2);
    CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new  CustomListAdapter(this,listData2);
    gridView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

    customListAdapter.setListData(listData2);
    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem newsData = (ListItem) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final TextView itemidtemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempid);
            itemidtemp.setText(newsData.getDate());
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + newsData.getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent series = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeriesActivity.class);
            series.putExtra("itemid", itemidtemp.getText());
            series.putExtra("title",listData2.get(position).getHeadline());
            startActivity(series);
            //          secondclick();

        }
    });

}

private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData2(String val) {

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetTeachingItems";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "GetTeachingItems";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://alive.devobal.com/PodioWebService.asmx?op=GetTeachingItems";

    Log.v("bbbbbbbbb","getdata2");
    ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    List<String> headlines = new LinkedList<>();

    Email = "dtiadmin1";
    Password = "DevObal1916";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        aht.debug = true;
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        Log.v("PCount", "" + resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount());
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        SoapObject obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;

        obj1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("diffgram");
        obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");

        //SrtVv="";
        for (int j = 0; j < obj2.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            obj4 = (SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(j);

            ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
            newsData.setUrl(obj4.getProperty(3).toString());
            newsData.setHeadline(obj4.getProperty(1).toString());
            newsData.setReporterName(/*obj4.getProperty(2).toString()*/"bnr");
            newsData.setDate(obj4.getProperty(0).toString());

            listMockData.add(newsData);

        }

        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
        Response = res.toString();



        String strV = response.getProperty(0).toString();

        Log.v("TAG", response.toString());
        Log.v("TAG", res.toString());
        return listMockData;
        //return nameValues;
        // Log.v("TAG", com.WsApp.adapters.Constants.name);
    } catch (MalformedJsonException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}




public void tab3Data(){
    listData1 = getListData1("");

    Log.v("aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaa"+listData1.size());

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list1);
    CustomListAdapter customListAdapter =new  CustomListAdapter(this,listData1);
    listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

    customListAdapter.setListData(listData1);
    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem newsData = (ListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final TextView itemidtemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempid);
            itemidtemp.setText(newsData.getDate());
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + newsData.getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent series = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeriesActivity.class);
            series.putExtra("itemid", itemidtemp.getText());
            series.putExtra("title",listData1.get(position).getHeadline());
            startActivity(series);
            //          secondclick();

        }
    });
}



private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData1(String val) {

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetMRTItems";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "GetMRTItems";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://alive.devobal.com/PodioWebService.asmx?op=GetMRTItems";

    Log.v("aaaaaaaaa","getdata1");
    ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    List<String> headlines = new LinkedList<>();

    Email = "dtiadmin1";
    Password = "DevObal1916";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        aht.debug = true;
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        Log.v("PCount", "" + resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount());
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        SoapObject obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;

        obj1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("diffgram");
        obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");

        //SrtVv="";
        for (int j = 0; j < obj2.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            obj4 = (SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(j);

            ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
            newsData.setUrl(obj4.getProperty(3).toString());
            newsData.setHeadline(obj4.getProperty(1).toString());
            newsData.setReporterName(obj4.getProperty(2).toString()/*"nnb"*/);
            newsData.setDate(obj4.getProperty(0).toString());

            listMockData.add(newsData);

        }

        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
        Response = res.toString();


        String strV = response.getProperty(0).toString();

        Log.v("TAG", response.toString());
        Log.v("TAG", res.toString());
        return listMockData;
        //return nameValues;
        // Log.v("TAG", com.WsApp.adapters.Constants.name);
    } catch (MalformedJsonException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private ArrayList<ListItem> getListDataSelectedItem(String val) {

    String METHOD_NAME1 = "GetTeachingSeries";
    String NAMESPACE1 = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String URL1 = "http://alive.devobal.com/PodioWebService.asmx?op=GetTeachingSeries";
    String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/GetTeachingSeries";

    ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    List<String> headlines = new LinkedList<>();

    Email = "dtiadmin1";
    Password = "DevObal1916";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, METHOD_NAME1);
    request.addProperty("itemId", val.toString());
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL1);

    try {
        aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        aht.debug = true;
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION1, soapEnvelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        Log.v("PCount", "" + resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount());
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        //Response = response.toString();
        SoapObject obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;

        obj1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("diffgram");
        obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");

        //SrtVv="";
        for (int j = 0; j < obj2.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            obj4 = (SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(j);

            ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
            newsData.setUrl("http://lh5.ggpht.com/_hepKlJWopDg/TB-_WXikaYI/AAAAAAAAElI/715k4NvBM4w/s144-c/IMG_0075.JPG");
            newsData.setHeadline(obj4.getProperty(1).toString());
            newsData.setReporterName(obj4.getProperty(2).toString());
            newsData.setDate(obj4.getProperty(0).toString());
            listMockData.add(newsData);

        }

        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
        Response = res.toString();

        String strV = response.getProperty(0).toString();

        Log.v("TAG", response.toString());
        Log.v("TAG", res.toString());
        return listMockData;
        //return nameValues;
        // Log.v("TAG", com.WsApp.adapters.Constants.name);
    } catch (MalformedJsonException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

//    @Override
//    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

//   }

//    @Override
//    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

//   }

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

/*  private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private final Context context;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context= context;

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView tView = new TextView(context);
        position++;
        tView.setText("Page number: " + position);
        tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tView.setTextSize(20);
        container.addView(tView);
        return tView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }
} */

public boolean netCheck(){

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    boolean bs_netcheck = false ;
    if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
            || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {
        //notify user you are not online
        bs_netcheck =true;

    }
    return bs_netcheck;
}

public void displayAlert()
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Please Check Your Internet Connection and Try Again")
            .setTitle("Network Error")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            .show();
}
}
```

Comment: There is way to much code to go through, please limit it to an [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i can't understand what u say can you please explain in detail